# How to add glossy texture to Principled Shader?

Tags: node-editor

How can I add a glossy shader to the Principled Shader? I tried to Mix RGB the diffuse with the glossy and connect them to the base color (PRINCIPLED SHADER) but it doesn't work fine... How can I do?[image]

Comment: There are several ways to do it, for example you could plug an Image Texture in the Glossy socket to determine which parts will be glossy, you have to create this Image Texture from your original image, then make it a SPEC (specular) image with a soft like CrazyBump

Comment: Okay, but the glossy shader I have to plug it to Mix Shader with the Principled shader?

Answer (score 2):

I'm am so new here I hesitate to even chime in, but I have been (and this may not be the right way) adding the mix shader to the output of the principled shader and connecting emission shades to the other mix input with success.  I think it shoukd work with a glossy shader as well, but again I am super new here and this is my Virgin answer so I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Karol, here is a basic node organisation for this kind of texture:

- Use a soft like CrazyBump or other to convert your ground picture to Normal and Specular pictures.
- Load them in Image Texture nodes, choose Non-Color Data.
- Plug the Normal map into the Normal sockets of the Diffuse and Glossy nodes.
- Put a Converter > Math node (Multiply mode) between the Spec and the Mix so that you can control the intensity of the Glossy effect.

[image]

same but with the Principled, plug the Spec in the Roughness socket (= Glossy):

[image]

Comment: So, the Roughness texture and the Glossy texture are the same?

Comment: yes it looks like the Roughness = Glossy + Fresnel

Comment: Thanks! It was basically the thing I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what your question is about but I'm assuming you want to make your scene more glossy.
(Also, the image is too small. It's very hard to see anything of the node setup)

To add more gloss with the Principled BSDF you would simply reduce the Roughness value. 
If you have a texture plugged into the Roughness, you can add a Color Ramp in between and make it darker. (I.e. less rough)

Comment: So, the Roughness texture and the Glossy texture are the same?

Comment: Not the same, but more or less the opposite. If you have a Glossy texture, simply invert it.